# Saving AVAudioRecorder output online

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

Is it possible to save the audio output of AVAudioRecorder on a webserver instead of saving it on the local iphone filesystem ? 
there is a method with the signature initWithURL:settings:error: but according to the documentation it only allows to save to the filesystem.

br,
martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *networkRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSInputStream* fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath: filePath]; 
[networkRequest setHTTPBodyStream:fileStream];

NSURLConnection* theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:networkRequest delegate:self];
```

This is just sample you can create full Request and Stream it to server, filePath will be physical path of file

Answer (score 0):

The Best idea here is to use a library such as ASIHTTPRequest to send the saved file online after you record it.